# How do you typecheck an array variable that's "as const"?

Tags: typescript, types

Here's my code:

```
export type Types = 'a' | 'b';

export type MyPartials = {
  readonly [P in keyof Types]?: number;
};

export interface MyI {
  readonly name: string;  
  readonly myPartials: MyPartials;
}

export const myIs = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    myPartials: {a: 5},
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    myPartials: {},
  },
  {
    name: 'C',
    myPartials: {},
  },
] as const;

const typeCheck = (arr: readonly MyI[]): void => {};

typeCheck(myIs); //error on arg
```

[You can play with this here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqzgGc4F44DkAhgXAD6EBGBA3AFB2iSwKZwCyiACkbAJZEANjnwBvOnDhRgRACYQAdoMRwA2lzh8FcANbBEEAGbpMWALoB%20AFxwFAVwC2lYFHoBfeo3DR4WmC8MiAGNUTgBJOHFJaTlFZVsiB2AbLBgoLQBzGkkJKRl5JRUHbl4YAWEbTh5%20ISx3BiYfOCDFVLhisJE1XKjJBKSbAgBBAgAaXMli6rLam1EiGwBWN3HJFZ6J-uTCACExzanS8qw59bXVyM2FRO2CAGF9vvaSmorIs7h1szgiHBaFVKef5tJAoO4AC2AQR0eDgAApeFAbDECvFwqozABKGwANwgfFkeAAfO9PKDgBCoTo4R0sJiaEA) This is giving me an error message I can't understand, mainly because it's so verbose I'm not sure where my eyes are supposed to land. The whole point of this is to typecheck that every element in the array is a `MyI`.  Why can't I pass this into a function that accepts `MyI[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix `MyPartials`:

```
export type MyPartials = {
  readonly [P in Types]?: number;
};
```

Comment: That last suggestion makes my code compile.

Comment: That's all, indeed. No need for `Readonly<MyI[]>` :)